# Проблемы с телепортацией в unity + c#

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity-container

Пытаюсь заставить игрока переместиться при падении c помощью этой строчки кода

```
public GameObject TLP;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.tag=="Player")
    {
        col.transform.position = TLP.transform.position;
    }
}
```

Тэг Player поставил, кубик в качестве телепорта указал. в результате получается что при попадании в зону коллайдера мелькает кадр якобы персонаж телепортировался и он остается на том же месте. Что не так? В unity новичок. Заранее спасибо

Comment: а персонаж так же остался стоять на месте?

Comment: вместо OnTriggerEnter пиши OnTriggerStay и сообщай о результатах.

Comment: Проверь, работает ли вообще соприкосновение с помощью print, если нет, то значит проблема именно в этом В ином случае ошибка явно не в этом куске кода